# Check and load a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [modinfo() equivalent INSIDE kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881581/modinfo-equivalent-inside-kernel)

I need to check whether a particular module ( abc.ko ) is loaded or not in a e1000 network driver. if abc.ko is not loaded, it has to be loaded. How can we achieve this in the driver code ?

Comment: I'm slightly dubious as to what you are trying to achieve and if this is "the right way". Usually, unless modules ACTUALLY use each other, they shouldn't be checking they are loaded, or try to load some other module. It seems like the wrong way to go about something. [As in, if a kernel module actuall DOES need some other module, the module loading mechanism already knows how to solve that]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsmod` for check the mods loaded, and `modinfo e1000` for more driver info.
To **load** the module, use `modprobe (module)`, and for **unload** `modprobe -r (module)`